# No DSM data available for the component (Gradle Multi-Project)

Tags: gradle, sonarqube, sonarqube-5.0

I have just upgraded to Sonarqube 5 (from a very old 2.14).

When building a (new) project (multi-project gradle build, with gradle `2.3-rc-3`), the build is successful and I see code violations ok on the sonar console.

When I click on the Design link, I get

`No DSM data available for the component`

After looking for similar questions/answers, I have checked `./build/tmp/sonarRunner/sonar-project.properties` and it contains `<project>.sonar.binaries` entries which look correct.

**UPDATE:**

I just tried with a clean 5.0 install; same result. So I installed 4.5.2 (again a new, clean, db) and it works fine, so it looks like it's an issue with 5.0 only.

I am building spring-amqp from [this branch](https://github.com/garyrussell/spring-amqp/tree/sonar) with...

```
./gradlew build sonarRunner -Dsonar.host.url=http://xxxxx:9000 \ 
  -Dsonar.jdbc.url=jdbc:oracle:thin:@xxxxx:1521/XE \
  -Dsonar.jdbc.username=xxxxx -Dsonar.jdbc.password=xxxxx
```

Comment: We've never tested the DSM with Gradle-based projects. I don't expect the DSM at project level because we get the dependency information from Maven for the moment, but it should work at "module" level. Can you confirm?

Comment: It works fine on our "production" 4.3 (and 4.5) servers. I am using the same build script at home against my 5.0 server, which is not working. [This link](https://sonar43.spring.io/plugins/resource/3500?page=org.sonar.plugins.design.ui.page.DesignPage) is to last night's successful build (4.3). [This one](https://sonar.spring.io/design/index/org.springframework.integration:spring-integration) is for a much larger project that runs ok against 4.5 (I haven't tried that one yet against my local server).

Comment: From what I can read on https://jira.codehaus.org/browse/SONAR-5672, you might get this message when there's no dependency or when there are too many of them (>200). On your local instance, are you analyzing the same projects as the one for which you gave the links?

Comment: Yes; the projects are identical; see the update to the question.

Comment: Yep; looks like that issue (5672) effectively turned off the feature for our projects. It's not very helpful to show on the dashboard that there's a tangle but no way to drill down to it.

Comment: OK, we had not noticed this so far because in the Maven world, the DSM at root project level is (almost) never empty. We'll fix this in 5.1. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because of the optimization done on [SONAR-5672](https://jira.codehaus.org/browse/SONAR-5672), the DSM is not displayed when there's no dependency at all - which is indeed problematic on non-Maven projects because you can't drilldown on lower levels directly from the root project.

We'll fix this in 5.1 with [SONAR-6176](https://jira.codehaus.org/browse/SONAR-6176).