# SonarQube: No DSM data available for the component (again)

Tags: sonarqube, sonarqube-5.0

I am using SonarQube Version 5.0, and I am starting an analysis with SonarQube Runner. mvn is not available.

I put all class file resulting from our Java sources into one directory, both *sonar.java.binaries* and the deprecated *sonar.binaries* point to it.

While running the analysis I got these messages:

```
14:59:13.921 DEBUG - Metric package_cycles is an internal metric computed by SonarQube. Please update your plugin.
14:59:13.921 DEBUG - Metric package_feedback_edges is an internal metric computed by SonarQube. Please update your plugin.
14:59:13.921 DEBUG - Metric package_tangles is an internal metric computed by SonarQube. Please update your plugin.
14:59:13.921 DEBUG - Metric package_edges_weight is an internal metric computed by SonarQube. Please update your plugin.
14:59:13.921 DEBUG - Metric dsm is an internal metric computed by SonarQube. Please update your plugin.
```

Clicking on project -> Design in the SonarQube web application I only saw the "No DSM data available for the component" message.

When I log in as Administrator then Settings -> Update Center tells me all plugins (Findbugs 3.1 and Java 2.9.1) are up to date.
Which one shall I update then?

what are the prerequisites in order to get a DSM with data in it?
Do I need some other plugin? Shall I set some specific properties? Does DSM creation only work with mvn  (and some dummy pom)?

Thank you and regards,
  Roland

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See the dialog on [my question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28415418/no-dsm-data-available-for-the-component-gradle-multi-project). It looks like DSM is disabled for complex projects now.